# How to automatically dismiss Outlook reminders after a certain time has passed?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Here's an extremely common scenario with Outlook:

1. I add an event to my calendar
2. A notification pops up, reminding me about the event
3. I ignore it or simply close the pop-up
4. The reminder pops up again at a later time, reminding me about a long gone meeting

Is it possible to have all Outlook reminders dismiss themselves after a certain time past the calendar event?

Comment: Have you tried hitting "dismiss" instead of closing the dialogue?

Comment: @ArtGertner sometimes I want the reminder at a later time, so I hit close instead of dismiss. However I never need the reminder on the next day.

Comment: It looks like you have just answered your own question. If you don't want to be reminded again, you hit  "dismiss". If you do want to get reminded, you hit "snooze"

Comment: @ArtGertner yes, but I also want Outlook to automatically dismiss reminders if it's X hours after the event

Comment: I see your point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JonathanReez

Try this macro, it may help:

```
Sub RemoveRemindersinSpecificTimeInterval()
    Dim objReminders As Outlook.Reminders
    Dim objReminder As Outlook.Reminder
    Dim dSpecificTime As Date
    Dim objItem

    Set objReminders = Outlook.Reminders
    'The following line refers to 1 day since the current time
    dSpecificTime = DateAdd("d", 1, Now)

    For Each objReminder In objReminders
        If objReminder.NextReminderDate <= Format(dSpecificTime, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") Then
           Set objItem = objReminder.Item
           objItem.ReminderSet = False
           objItem.Save
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

*About “dSpecificTime”, you can also replace “Now” with a specific date or time, like dSpecificTime = DateAdd(“m”, 1, 10-4-2017), or dSpecificTime = DateAdd(“h”, 2, 10-4-2017 8:30AM).*

Answer (score 1):

Try starting Outlook with `/cleanreminders` switch. If this provides the behavior that you want, then you can add this switch to the standard way you start Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exact answer to the question, but I thought it might be useful if we wanted this process to happen automatically. Thus, created vbs script which we can add in our task scheduler to run every 30 minutes to clear overdue reminders.

To automate the dismissal of overdue reminders, we will use a VBA script that can be added to our Task Scheduler. The VBA script will dismiss reminders programmatically and will be scheduled to run every 30 minutes, only on weekdays (Monday to Friday). This will eliminate the need for us to manually dismiss reminders and will save time and effort.

If You use outlook at multiple devices (Laptop & Desktop) you only need to setup this on any of the one device as it gets sync by outlook

Open Notepad or any other text editor.
Copy and paste the following code into the text editor:

```
Dim objApp  
Dim oRem 
Dim oEvent  
Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each oRem In objApp.Reminders
    Set oEvent = oRem.Item
    If oEvent.End <= Now Then
        If oRem.IsVisible Then      
            oRem.Dismiss
        End If 
    End If
    Set oEvent = Nothing
    Set oRem = Nothing
Next
Set objApp = Nothing
```

File name: clearReminders.vbs
File location in my case "D:\VBA\clearReminders.vbs"
Save the file with a name, for example, "clearReminders.vbs".

Process to schedule task as follows

1. Open the Task Scheduler by searching for it in the Windows search bar or by pressing Windows + R, typing "taskschd.msc", and pressing enter.
2. Click on "Create Task" on the right-hand side of the window.
3. Enter a name for the task, such as "  Dismiss Reminders Scheduler".
4. In General Tab
   security options block select
   "Run only when user is logged on"
5. Click on the "Triggers" tab, then click "New".
6. "Select "Weekly" as the trigger and set it for Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday. Then, set the start time to 12:01:00 AM, so that the script runs every 30 minutes from 12:31 AM, 1:01 AM, and so on, to clear the reminders automatically."
7. Under "Advanced settings", select "Repeat task every:" and enter "30 minutes" in the field next to it.
8. Under "Duration", select "Indefinitely" if you want the task to run until you stop it manually.

   [Trigger ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9vNV.png)
9. Click on the "Actions" tab, then click "New".
10. Select "Start a program" as the action and enter "D:\VBA\clearReminders.vbs " in the "Program/script" field.
11. you may have saved file at different location.

    [Action ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1XW3.png)
12. Click "OK" to close the action settings, then click "OK" to close the task settings.
13. Your VBScript will now run every 30 minutes from Monday to Friday according to the schedule you set up.

Note:

1.Outlook provide this functionality in some versions but there is no such option in my case
as we might be using volume license of outlook so do not have check box.

2.This is basic implementation if there are any edge cases, please let me know.